# Xinet tftp timeout

Tags: networking, tftp

I trying to set up a PXE boot server.

Everything is working but the TFTP client is timing out.

```
TFTP connection timeout
```

I am using this to setup the TFTP server.
 http://www.davidsudjiman.info/2006/03/27/installing-and-setting-tftpd-in-ubuntu/

/etc/xinet.d/tftp

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

ps ax|grep tftp doesn't return it running.

any idea's what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a very old tutorial you have there.

What version of Ubuntu are you using ?

A more up to date tutorial can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro

From the wiki, you need to use the tftpd-hpa server (there are 2 servers in the repos).

```
sudo apt-get -y install tftpd-hpa
sudo /etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd stop
sudo update-rc.d -f openbsd-inetd remove
sudo sed -i s/no/yes/ /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
sudo /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start
```

> Ubuntu installs the openbsd-inetd pakcage when the tfpd-hpa package is installed. In our example we will simply run TFTP as a daemon and will always be listening for connections.

If you are still having a problem with a time out, can you confirm the tftpd-hpa server is running and update your question.